# Creating several files in different directories

Tags: bash

I need to create 1000 input files containing:

x=i,  i varies from 1 to 1000

y=5

Each file is to be placed in a separate directory.
I tried:

```
mkdir inp
cd inp
max=1000
for ((i=1;i<=max;i++)); do
    mkdir dir{$i}
    cd dir{$i}
    cat input_file.txt
    x=i > input_file.txt
    y=5 >> input_file.txt
    cd inp
done
```

Which fails

Comment: Does any of our response solve you issue you? If yes, please tick as **Accepted** the appropriate answer; if not, please explain what didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want something like this:

```
for ((i=1;i<=1000;i++)); do
    mkdir -p inp/dir$i
    printf 'x=%s\ny=5s\n' "$i" > inp/dir$i/input_file.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong, it would be better with `cd ..` instead of `cd inp`, and `touch` instead of `cat` (`cat` command would return an error for a non existant file, `touch` create it). Also, use `echo` command (or `printf` as mentionned in [@terdon answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1195600/829702)) to write into a file.

So if you just want to use your code without error, you can do that as below :

```
mkdir -p inp
cd inp
max=1000
for ((i=1;i<=max;i++)); do
    mkdir -p dir{$i}
    cd dir{$i}
    touch input_file.txt
    echo x=i >> input_file.txt
    echo y=5 >> input_file.txt
    cd ..
done
```

---

NB : if you want your file named as `dir1`, `dir2`, ... instead of `dir{1}`, `dir{2}`, ..., just remove `{}` in `mkdir` and `cd` command inside your loop :

```
    mkdir -p dir$i
    cd dir$i
```

---

NB2 : You can simplify your code by removing `max` value, or getting `max` value as parameter; with a script named `script.sh`, it would be like that when executing it:

```
script.sh 100
```

and the code :

```
mkdir -p inp
cd inp
for ((i=1;i<=$1;i++)); do
    mkdir -p dir$i
    cd dir$i
    touch input_file.txt
    echo x=$i >> input_file.txt
    echo y=5 >> input_file.txt
    cd ..
done
```